# How to show name field in signup form drupal 7

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I am using Profile 2 to add fields in registration form in drupal 7.
now i want to show name fields before username and password fields, how can i do it ?

Answer (score 1):

Edit: I'm sorry, I had misunderstood your question (left my previous answer for history).

Try [Profile2 Registration Path](https://drupal.org/project/profile2_regpath). It promises to merge both your account and profile information on a custom path. Use the `.htaccess`file to redirect from `user/register` to the new URL or install one of the various redirect modules.

Afterwards you might want to follow the approach from my previous answer to correct the order:

Use [hook_form_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7) to set the weights of the fields according to your needs. You can do so by inserting somthing similar to

```
function yourthemename_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'user_register_form') {
    $form['field_firstname']['#weight'] = -20;
    $form['field_lastname']['#weight'] = -19;
  }
}
```

in the `template.php` of your theme.

Be aware that I'am using the build in profile fields instead of Profile2 but it should work the same way. If you're not sure how your profile fields are to be accessed download and enable `devel`module, set permissions to allow guests to access developer information and insert a `dpm($form)`in the above function.